# Install Twilio on Heroku Parse Server

Tags: node.js, heroku, parse-platform, npm, parse-cloud-code

I've got a working Parse Server running on Heroku, and I'm trying to get my Twilio cloud code working. As soon as I add `var twilio = require('twilio')(twilioAccountSid, twilioAuthToken);` to my main.js, the app breaks. The migration guide from Parse.com (https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Migrating-an-Existing-Parse-App#3-cloud-code) shows that Twilio should be installed from the "official npm module". How does one do that? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to modify package.json, adding `"twilio": "~2.9.0"` as a dependency. I was also able to troubleshoot this better by installing the Heroku toolbelt, and running `heroku logs --tail  --app your_app_name` from the terminal. I originally installed twilio via the Heroku toolbelt, by running `heroku run npm install twilio --app your_app_name`, but I'm not sure if that was required or not.

Comment: `heroku run npm install twilio --app your_app_name` will not do anything. That's going to start a new ephemeral Heroku dyno (all Heroku processes are ephemeral), install it on that, then it will be deleted. You need to add it to the package.json and commit + push those changes.

You did this, I just wanted to be clear that the run step is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Jeff. Makes total sense.